# How do I clear the Run box history in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, control-panel, run-dialog

Since there's no longer a taskbar/start menu Control Panel, how do you clear the history of the Run box in Windows 8?

Comment: there is still a Control panel btw...

Comment: @MimiEAM I never said there isn't. I said there's no Taskbar/Start Menu Control Panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following are the steps to clear history of the Run box:

1. Go to the Start screen, and type `regedit` and open click on `regedit` to open the **Registry Editor**
2. Navigate to the key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`
3. On the right of the screen, there are keys that contain the recently entered commands on the Run Box. Delete the ones that you want to delete
   [image: Registry Editor]
4. Log off and Log back on.

That should delete history from the Run menu.

The UI Way to delete History

1. Type `Clear History` in the **Search** box. Then click on **Settings** on the Charms menu
   [image: Select Delete Search History]
2. Finally select **Delete History** to clear the history
   [image: Delete History]

However, that method deletes more than just the search history of Run Box. It also deletes history from other applications like File Explorer.

Comment: There's really no actual UI way to do this?

Comment: There is actually a UI way to delete history. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: It should be accepted, the edit make it worth :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to erase the run history.

[image]

Comment: I hate "tools", but ccleaner is really good!

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me

```
rundll32 inetcpl.cpl ClearMyTracksByProcess 1
```

[Clear History From the Command Line](http://howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-ie7-browsing-history-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Just like in Windows 7 the easiest way to do this is using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Empty the registry key out:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths]
```

This will kill the typed Run history.